# NSTextView ligature attribute overridden

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, appkit, nstextview, nsfont

When setting the `.ligature` attribute on an `NSTextView`, it gets overridden when adding both a `.paragraphStyle` and `.baselineOffset` attribute at the same time. Here's the example, adding the below code

```swift
textView.textStorage?.setAttributes(
    [
        .ligature: 0,
        .font: NSFont(name: "FiraCode-Light", size: 12)!,
        .baselineOffset: 3.5,
        .paragraphStyle: {
            let p = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy()  as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
            p.lineHeightMultiple = 1.5
            p.lineSpacing = 10
            return p
        }()
    ],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.textView.string.count)
)
```

This should disable ligatures (see the `.ligature: 0` line) on the FiraCode font which has ligatures. If the lines below the `.font` attribute are removed, ligatures get disabled.

Here's what it looks like with ligatures (incorrectly) enabled:
[image: bad, but with ligatures]

And by disabling the `.paragraphStyle` and `.baselineOffset` the ligatures get disabled, but the needed line spacing is obviously gone.

[image: bad, but without ligatures]

Is this a bug with Apple's code? Or is there something I should be doing to disable this functionality.

Comment: Is the issue reproducable with Lucida Grande?

Comment: @Willeke I haven’t tried it but I can look into it.